# Scala - Expanding an argument list in a pattern matching expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I'm very new to Scala and trying to use it as an interface to Spark. I'm running into a problem making a generic CSV to DataFrame function.  For example, I've got a CSV with about 50 fields, the first of which are `task`, `name`, and `id`.  I can get the following to work:

```
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(txt))

reader.readAll().map(_ match {
  case Array(task, name, id, _*) => Row(task, name, id)
  case unexpectedArrayForm =>
    throw new RuntimeException("Record did not have correct number of fields: "+ unexpectedArrayForm.mkString(","))
})
```

However, I'd rather not have to hard code the number of fields needed to create a spark Row.  I tried this:

```
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(txt))

reader.readAll().map(_ match {
  case Array(args @ _*) => Row(args)
  case unexpectedArrayForm =>
    throw new RuntimeException("Record did not have correct number of fields: "+ unexpectedArrayForm.mkString(","))
})
```

But it just creates a Row object with a single element.  How can I make it expand the `args` in `Row(args)` so that if I have an array of N elements I'll get a Row with N elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(txt))

reader.readAll().map(_ match {
  case a: Array[String] => Row(a:_*)
  case unexpectedArrayForm =>
    throw new RuntimeException("Record did not have correct number of fields: "+ unexpectedArrayForm.mkString(","))
})
```

*Edited to correct omission of Array type*

Comment: I had to change it to `case a: Array[String] => Row(a:_*)` to get it to compile.  However, I'm still getting an error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3` when trying to access the `id` variable in `Row`, which makes me think that it's still not expanding the array to arguments of `Row`.

Comment: @SterlingParamore Make sure you don't have any rogue rows in the CSV data (for example, an empty line at the end of the file or something.)  Maybe change the case statement to say `case a: Array[String] if a.length > 3 => Row(a:_*)` and have another case statement that catches other Arrays and does nothing.

Comment: My `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error was unrelated to this.  Working now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Change your input to be variable length by adding `_*`:

```
Row(args:_*)
```

[This is what `Row` accepts per its `apply` signature](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/59d24c226a441db5f08c58ec407ba5873bd3b954/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala#L41).

In fact, you don't even need to do anything other than pass this in to the Row as it is already of the right sequence type.

```
reader.readAll().map(Row(_:_*))
```